# Some js files are missing when i try to run on PROD profile

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc, spring-boot, dependencies, jhipster

I  have app on jhipster generator, i have some issues with three JS, they were not installed by npm or bower, they were downloaded and put into the project, they are injected into the index and in the dev profile they work perfectly, but when the prod profile is active and i run the project,he no recognized the JS and they give this error

```
    Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myAPP due to:
    Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module autocomplete due to:
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/nomod?p0=autocomplete
```

Im using this autocomplete https://github.com/JustGoscha/allmighty-autocomplete,
and toastr and websocket. but i dont know where i can put that files for that the project recognize those js when i run the project in PROD profile. Any ideas ?

Comment: it depends on where you injected them in index.html as some portions are injected/overwirtten by gulp-inject based on bower dependencies. For your example, you should have used bower.

Comment: Try running `gulp build` and any errors during the prod build process should be printed in the console